# Laravel - "The file failed to upload" on shared hosting

Tags: laravel, laravel-api

So im currently working on a simple REST API in Laravel. I have a post function which sends entered data to database and uploads one file. Everything works fine on local. Image is uploading to storage/public/my_directory. I also have public access to the uploaded image by going to address "localhost://storage/my_directory/my_file.jpg".
The problem is that after deploying the project to shared hosting i cant upload files.
[Im just getting this meaningless error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdmKE.png)

Thats how my function looks like:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'slug' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'country' => 'required',
            'file' => 'required|image',
            'category' => 'required',
        ]);

        $img = $request->file('file')->store('public/images');
        $request->merge(['image' => $img]);

        $product = Product::create($request->all());

        return dd($product);
}
```

And additionally filesystems.php file:

```
'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
            'throw' => false,
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => false,
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
            'throw' => false,
        ],

    ],
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Somewhere there are some logs that hopefully have some more detail.  Perhaps there is a permissions error or something like that but the logs should point you in the right direction.

Comment: How big is the file? What's your upload_max_filesize and post_max_size setting?

Comment: @ceejayoz i was afraid that file size might be too big but it also fails even with 200byte image